# How to put computed functions inside switch statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

Can anyone please help me putting the following if else into switch statement ??

```
var computed ={
idOnly : function () {},
classOnly : function () {},
selectAllElements: function () {},
eitherOne : function () {}
}

// From here i need to put in Switch
if (computed.idOnly(selector)) {
    var getById = document.getElementById(selectorArray[1]);
    Allelements.push(getById);
} else if (computed.classOnly(selector)) {
    var getByClass = document.getElementsByClassName(selectorArray[1]);

    computed.selectAllElements(getByClass, Allelements);
} else {
    var getByTags = document.getElementsByTagName(selectorArray[0]);

    if (selectorArray.length === 1) {
        computed.selectAllElements(getByTags, Allelements);
    } else if (selectorArray.length === 2) {
        computed.eitherOne(
            byId,
            byClass,
            byTag,
            false,
            Allelements
        );
    } else if (selectorArray.length === 3) {
        computed.eitherOne(
            byId,
            byClass,
            byTag,
            true,
            Allelements
        );
    }
}
```

I only need to put it inside Switch statement I will be really really thankful as i can not figure out how to do it ?

Comment: can you help me put this inside switch statement or its not possible ?

Comment: its nothing main , just trying to understand few concepts where i been stuck on for quite sometime , is it possible or no ?

Answer (score -1):

No conditional branches at all:

```
computed.eitherOne(
   ...( selectorArray.length === 1 ? [getByTags] : [byId, byClass, byTag, selectorArray.length === 3] ),
   Allelements
);
```

or if you really want a switch:

```
switch(selectorArray.length){
 case 1:
  computed.eitherOne(getByTags, Allelements);
 break;
 case 2:
   computed.eitherOne(byId, byClass, byTag, false);
 break;
 case 3:
   computed.eitherOne(byId, byClass, byTag, true);
 break;
}
```

Comment: But it says selectorArray.length is not defined ?

Comment: This has solved the second if else problem starting from `getByTags` but have solved the first if else statement , i will really thankful if you can help me out with the first one ?